# How to control the fling effect in HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, swipe-gesture

I want to implement a `HorizontalScrollView` with four `TextView`s having text say("First view", "Second View", "Third View", "Fourth View") such that `HorizontalScrollView` will display only one center `TextView` at one time and when user scrolls/swipe, he/she will be able to move to the next text only(irrespective of the velocity of scroll/swipe) so that i can display a different image corresponding to the text visible in `HorizontalScrollView` at that time.

It means if user is at "Second View" and want to see the "Fourth view" he has to see the "Third View" also.

I am new to the Android. kindly help!

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: i have tried subclassing HorizontalScrollView to chang the fling method. But dont know how to control the swipe velocity and max swipe distance.

Comment: take a look at this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: Thanks!! After trying a lot. I came to a solution:

Answer (score 2):

In this example I override the fling() method and dividing the velocity by 4 causing the Fling to be weaker:

```
@Override
    public void fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_FLING;
        final int x = getScrollX();
        final int y = getScrollY();

        mScroller.fling(x, y, velocityX/4, velocityY/4, Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! After trying a lot. I came to a solution: I have used Gallery widget and customize it to serve my purpose.

//Customized Gallery Class: SlowGallery.java

```
public class SlowGallery extends Gallery {

public SlowGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public SlowGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SlowGallery(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}


@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
{

    //limit the max speed in either direction
    if (velocityX > 400.0f)
    {
        velocityX = 400.0f;
    }
    else if(velocityX < 400.0f)
    {
        velocityX = -400.0f;
    }
    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);


    //return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) 
{
    return false;
}
```

}

now in your main Activity Class add following code in oncreate function:

```
 Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

then create ImageAdapter class as:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mText = {
            "View 1","View 2", "View 3", "View 4"
    };
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
     }


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return mText.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView textview = new TextView(mContext);             textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textview.setText(mText[position]);
    textview.setFocusable(true);
    textview.setTextSize(16);
    textview.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(230, 100));
    textview.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
         changePosition(position, textview);

    return textview;

}
```

Thats it!! :)